# "From:" address is sometimes the Google Group list email

Tags: google-groups

I've set up a Google Group and I'm observing some unexpected behavior with the From: address when members email the group. Sometimes From: is set to the sender's name and email address (the desired behavior), but other times I get:

```
From: 'full name' via My Group Name <my-group@googlegroups.com>
```

This is masking the sender's email address, making it hard to reply to the sender rather than the list and complicating future searching/filtering. Under what conditions does Google rewrite the From address, and can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 10):

This masking happens as Google Groups forward incoming messages: In case the sender has strict email delivery settings, Google needs to show that it redirected the message (and thereby became the new sender of the message). Otherwise, clients would reject it as being spoofed.

Hitting replying to those messages *should* still work as the reply-to address gets correctly set.

From the [product forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/Apps/0lsuYZV87NU):

> This is to prevent rejections of messages from senders whose domains have a 'reject' DMARC policy. The change involves re-writing the From address so that it no longer points to the original sender. In doing so, the received messages display the sender as ‘User Name’ via .

Comment: It appears this behavior also occurs if the DMARC policy is `quarantine`, in addition to `reject`.